# Drag button inside a field to a set boundary

Tags: python, tkinter

It's been a number of years since I asked for help. I'm creating a number of drag and drop buttons inside a frame. When the button is released It triggers that works fine. I have set up a boundary inside the button_drag().The problem I'm having is if the button is dragged right up to the boundary the button fails to trigger. Of course code is worth a thousand words so I made up a small code which shows the approach i'm taking using just one button. I have tried placing the button inside it's own canvas and fiddled around with mouse Info. I hope someone can help. thanks

```
root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")

frame = Frame(root,bg="grey40")
frame.config(width=200,height = 200)
frame.pack()
frame.place(x=150, y=150, anchor=CENTER)

def button_push():
    print("Button Pressed")

def button_drag(event):
    global Yevent
    x = event.x + event.widget.winfo_x()
    y = event.y + event.widget.winfo_y()
    Yevent = y
    if y > 180:
        y = 180
    event.widget.place(x=x, y=y, anchor="s")

button = Button(frame, text="button1", font='TkDefaultFont', fg="slate grey",command=lambda: button_push())
button.place(x=50,y=50)
button.bind("<B1-Motion>",button_drag)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It appears the problem is that when you release the mouse button when the cursor is not over the button, the button doesn't fire. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

The normal behavior of buttons is to not call their command if you release the mouse button when the cursor is not over the button. This allows the user to prevent the button from being clicked if they change their mind after pressing the button.

If you want the button to be triggered no matter where the cursor is when the user releases the button, you'll have to add your own binding.

You'll want to have your binding return the string "break" so that the default behavior doesn't also cause the button to trigger.

```
button.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", lambda event: event.widget.invoke() and "break")
```